# Error Checking for GWT GSS in NetBeans

Tags: java, css, gwt, netbeans

I'm using GWT with their new GSS syntax for styling. In NetBeans, .gss files are not recognized, so there is no syntax highlighting. So, I set up .gss files to be treated like .css files. But now, GSS is flagged as syntax errors. Here is a small sample:

```
@def PANEL_BACKGROUND #eaeafc;
```

This gives the error "Unexpected token HASH found".

I couldn't find a plugin to properly validate GSS. Is there a way to customize this? I found that clicking the little error bubble gives me the option to disable these errors, though if possible, I'd like GSS to validate properly.

Comment: The CSS lexer won't understand the GSS syntax in the file. The lexer breaks up the files into tokens and when it encounters a GSS syntax it fails. The only way around this is to find a GSS editor.